# typing e exponent in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Please can anyone tell me how to get the following output in python:

```
9.4605e+12
```

I typed it that way

```
S_L = "2.998765e+08" 
print "S_L"
```

But it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get print a number with exponent notation by using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> my_num = 123456.7890
>>> print my_num
123456.789
>>> print '{0:e}'.format(my_num)
1.234568e+05
```

And in your case above, you are probably getting `S_L` as the output because you have quotes around `S_L`, which means it is getting interpreted as a string and not the contents of the `S_L` variable. In that specific case, you could do:

```
>>> S_L = "2.998765e+08"
>>> print S_L
2.998765e+08
```